# InnerHTML is moving tags out of order

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to change the inner HTML to display search results in a table

```
<tr class="searchresult" id="searchresult">
            <th colspan="9">No Data</th>
</tr>
```

This is the javascript

```
var str1 = "<c:forEach var=\"list\" items=\"${list}\">";
var str2 =" <th>${list.sabun}</th>";
var str3 = "<th>${list.name}</th>";
var str4 = "</c:forEach>";
document.getElementById("searchresult").innerHTML = str1;
document.getElementById("searchresult").innerHTML += str2;
document.getElementById("searchresult").innerHTML += str3;
document.getElementById("searchresult").innerHTML += str4;
```

This is the resulting html I get on the test webpage

```
<c:foreach var="list" items="${list}"></c:foreach>
<th>${list.sabun}</th>
<th>${list.name}</th>
```

I even tried putting all the str# variables in one line, that still didn't work.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: why you need to put jsp code inside js ?

Comment: `<c:foreach` is not html or javascript. Therefore it simply cannot be done in this way

Comment: @Swati so that I could just change the tag contents instead of creating a separate view

Comment: `th` can be nested with `tr` only

Comment: @aspiretojava, I have no idea why don't you just put the JSP stuff on the html template, there is really no need to use it in the javascript part. Then when the page is queried, the server will just emit the correct HTML out.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey i see thank you

Comment: @CHANist i get it now. i was approaching it wrong. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use that *loop* and pull data from it and add inside your `str` variable . i.e :

```
   <script>
      var str ="";
       <c:forEach var="list" items="${list}">
        str += "<th><c:out value='${list.sabun}'/></th><th><c:out value='${list.name}'/></th>";
       </c:forEach>
      document.getElementById("searchresult").innerHTML = str;
   </script>
```

(This code is not tested)

Comment: This code is going to throw `SyntaxError`

Comment: yes i know that's the reason i added in my answer `This code is not tested..`

Comment: @aspiretojava if you get syntax error try like this `"<th>${list.sabun}</th><th>${list.name}</th>"` there must be quotes issue in my code .